# Magento - why is using a custom block with direct SQL in list view slower than direct sql in list.phtml?

Tags: mysql, magento, block

In Magento we had a problem with extremely fast changing stocklevels & deliverytimes of products originating from a variety of suppliers.
We have over 400k products in catalogue, and about 50-150k changes in stocklevels every day, with popular products having hourly changes - there was no way Magento could keep up with this in a timely manner.

We solved most of this problem using direct sql in the product list (list.phtml), view (view.phtml) and in the shoppingcart.
This extremely simple query accesses - if needed - the table in our DB that holds the stocklevels, productstatus and deliverytimes for each product and displays this next to the product to assure we display accurate stock & deliverytime information to our custmers.

query:

```
$query = "SELECT external_stock, productstatus, deliveryperiod FROM products_supplierstatus WHERE sku='$sku'";

$data = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($query);
```

With php we loop through the status & stocklevels and depending a few factors we display a tekst that informs the customer about the expected deliverytime of this product.

So far, so good - Always worked like a charm and solved our problem.

However, we decided to combine these routine in a simple module, so we can always call the same block, and we would be able to manage changes for deliverytimes more easily (in 1 place instead of 3).

Sounded easy enough so we created a small module and called this in the list & view pages:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('dynamic/delivery')->setData('prodid', $_product->getId())->setTemplate('dvdo/showdelivery.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

also works great.. but: mainly noticeable on the list view the loading times of the pages is much longer than it used to be.

We hardly changed anything in the query or in the php that loops through the results and creates the html.
Because we need near-realtime stockinformation we do not cache these blocks.

What's the reason behind this?
Does it take so much extra resources in Magento to build this block compared to executing nearly the same code in the phtml file?

If anyone can point me in the right direction to get this module working properly, I would be extremely gratefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's too many factors for anyone to guess at the right answer.  You'll need to profile and debug this yourself.  Here's some guidance.

1. It may not be what you think.  Magento's a huge application, with many layers of abstraction that interact with each other, with so many different interactions that's it's often difficult to keep things straight.   You may have changed something else that's impacting performance. This is why you need to debug and profile
2. An intro to [`Varien_Profiler`](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/keeping-your-magento-fit-with-built-in-profiler/), the profiling class that ships with Magento
3. If you completely remove the contents of `dvdo/showdelivery.phtml` so it's a blank file, does the performance problem still happen?
4. Is this being rendered more times than you think it is? Is the block inside a loop? (some logging in our template can help reveal this)
5. What, exactly, is in your template file?  Your SQL query uses a SKU, but your block (presumably) uses the a product ID
6. Speaking of product ID, where is the `$_product` in `$_product->getId()` coming from?
7. What does your block class for `dynamic/delivery` look like?  Are there heavy operations in the PHP constructor?  Magento's `_construct` method? The `prepareLayout` method?
8. It's possible, although I doubt it, that the extra work of instantiating an additional class (your block), and loading another template file (the `phtml`), buts your particular system over some `*nix*` threshold for too many PHP classes or files opened at once.  This is more likely if your block instantiation is in a loop.
9. If may be your original SQL was something that you database system (MySQL?) could easily apply SQL caching to, but that whatever query you have in  `dvdo/showdelivery.phtml` is not something it can easily cache on the SQL level.

If you figure it out, be sure to update the comments — I'd be interested in hearing what it eventually was.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
We profiled the query and optimized it, but the problem still remained.
It looks like the problem was the query in the block, probably due to query caching. We took the query outside the block, back into the various phtml files, and passed the data to the block, and the problem was resolved.

Again, many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you replace $this->getLayout()->createBlock('dynamic/delivery')  with block created via .xml by placing nodes and values in proper handle.

I am not sure if these blocks are conditional.Unless they are conditional blocks for faster implementation using XML file for block creation will be faster.